# Applying `position: fixed` to `body` makes it lose the scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I'm trying something, where I apply `position: fixed` to the `body` tag of a webpage. Then I proceed to apply all the sides (top, bottom, left, right) to 0 so that it covers all the viewport.

My expectation was that it would be virtually the same as not having added the fixed position at all, but now I don't get any scrollbars to move the page. If I apply `overflow: scroll`, dummy disabled scrollbars appear, and not the real ones that can get me to the bottom of the page.

I'm trying all this stuff for an extension. That's why I want to move the `body` tag.

Note: this also happens if I apply all the styling on the `html` tag.

Comment: Position fixed on body is a bad idea. You take the complete body out of the document flow. Overflow: scroll will alway add scrollbars and you are not getting dummy. There is nothing to scroll when you fix an element. It would be strange if I could scroll a **fixed** element.

Comment: May be its because of you have fixed the position of your body, and its not displaying scroll bars. I think you should use a <div> for your all other stuff. And let be fixed it not whole <body>

Comment: You should explain for what you are trying to achieve? and make a simple demo. It is very confusing right now.

Comment: @sdcr, I'm making a Chrome extension, so I have no control on the pages. I know it might not be the best idea, but my question is specifically about the `position: fixed` behavior.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez i'm not familiar with creating an extension. But you could also style the `<html>` tag as the parent.

Comment: @sdcr, I get the same result as described here.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez I don't know if this help - http://jsfiddle.net/xvdz12Ln/

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez cool, should I post that as an answer? is there anything else?

Comment: @sdcr, yes, it's the answer. Apply styling to both `html` and `body`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per comment and answer suggested, you basically cannot have the scroll bar on a `position:fixed` element, but you can have it on the child element, so in this case, set the `<html>` tag as fixed, and `<body>` to overflow.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1tgq0xsm/)**

```css
html {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: silver;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background: aqua;
}
```

```html
content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content
```

Answer (score 2):

> An element with position:fixed is fixed with respect to the viewport.
>   It stays where it is, even if the document is scrolled.
>   
> ...
>
> Elements with fixed positioning are fixed with respect to the
>   viewport—the viewport is always their containing block. They always
>   appear at the same place inside the browser window when viewed on
>   screen

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Fixed_positioning

Basically, `position:fixed` is probably not what you want. And if it is, you don't want to be using it on the `body` tag.

Comment: I don't understand this. Yes, the fixed position makes it stay where it is. But the content inside the fixed element is still overflowing, right? Why is the fixed element (not the viewport) not showing tabs?

Comment: Is it because the `body` tag is special?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez It's because you are making it so that the body [never leaves the viewport](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#viewport) by taking it out of the flow and making it fit exactly within each edge. And the spec says that `position:fixed` elements [will not move when scrolled](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position).

Comment: But I don't want to scroll the viewport. I want to scroll the content inside the `body`, which now is effectively independent of the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, making the body tag `position: fixed` effectually removes it from document flow by making it's position relative to the viewport rather than the rest of the document.

When you set the position alter properties (`top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`) you made the body stretch to cover the viewable window (See @AlexW's answer). The scrollbars will now disappear. Setting the `overflow` doesn't have any effect because the body is effectively clipping off it's content.

If you wanted this to work you could possibly inject another element within body that has `overflow: auto` *(Untested)*, but it would be better to find a more appropriate method of doing what you're trying to do.