# Not full width footer on my web page in mobile view

Tags: html, css

In my Portfolio, I can't get my footer a full width of 100% and i have a small white line in the right of the website So here is the source codes and some screenshots.

But if you want you can see the problem in your device just type in the URL: beraysezgin.com, and going to the about section.

The codes and the screenshots:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpXXc.png)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pin2iqld7j8bhzs/stackoverflow.zip?dl=0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHZtH.png)

Comment: Please include code in the question. Links to code and pictures of code aren't helpful to the community. Links go stale. Pictures aren't searchable. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code.

I couldn't see  any white line in the right side of the website.

in your about.php add

`<footer style='width:100%'>`

Or

go to your stylesheet page and add

```
footer{width:100%;}
```

which will give you a **100%** width.

**UPDATE**

For Removing that white space on the right side of the body :

Try This on your stylesheet page :

```
body{
width:100%;
}
```

**Update**

and add this too

```
html {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

let me know you still face that problem.

**cheers!**

Comment: I just added a screenshots to the question where you can see the white blank line in the right side of the page and this is a screenshot of the code where i have written the 100% code [link](https://imgur.com/a/Hbtth)

Comment: on what device are you testing this website ?

Comment: I have updated the answer, plz check it and let me know.

Comment: It's ok now the white line has gone but if i add position:fixed i cannot scroll down the page

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019200/applying-position-fixed-to-body-makes-it-lose-the-scrollbars).

Comment: It not helps i have searched everywhere nothing helps